# "Uncha lamba kad" rap verse lyrics

Tags: lyrics, rap

It's a Bollywood song from movie "Welcome". YouTube link mentioned above and the lyrics are as given below.

https://www.filmyquotes.com/songs/1170

Can anyone tell what are the lyrics of the rap verse
[from 0:12 to 0:22 in YouTube link] ? the language ? and what does it mean ?

Comment: Look like Punjabi but I'm no expert. Why are you asking for the meaning? There is a translation on the web page you linked to. There are lyrics to, but transliterated. You want them in the original script?

Comment: @xhienne i am not asking for the part that is there already in the link... there is a part where lyrics are just saying: "rap verse" !

listen to the part 0:12 to 0:22 in youtube link